# How to print the number into the middle of string with specific format?

Tags: c++, string, string-formatting, c-strings

I have something like this:

```
 count++;
 sprintf(buf, "%d", count);
 char * wyn1 = " <span font='26'><b>buf</b></span>";
 gtk_label_set_markup( GTK_LABEL( wynik1 ), wyn1 );
```

but it the value of `count` is never printed into the `wyn1`.

How to print the value of `buf` into `wyn1` following this specific format?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I edited your question because it was in terrible state (that's why you were receiving negative votes from some users). Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [About page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) to avoid this kind of situation in the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<span font='26'><b>` = 19 characters
`</b></span>` = 11 characters
`'\0'` = 1 character
and lets say that `count` will not require more than 3 digits. Then you could just print it directly into `wyn1` variable in that format (`buf` can be omitted):

```
char * wyn1 = malloc(19 + 3 + 11 + 1);
sprintf(wyn1, "<span font='26'><b>%3d</b></span>", count);
```

But since this is actually tagged as [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), you should simply use [`std::ostringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/ostringstream/):

```
std::ostringstream os;
os << "<span font='26'><b>" << count << "</b></span>";
```

and after that `os.str().c_str()` will be usable just like `wyn1` in previous code, but yet even better, lifetime of this C-string will be tied to the temporary copy of `std::string` object retrieved from the stream, so you don't need to do the memory management on your own.

Comment: @user2141238: Check my first revision: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15702421/1